# How to add a predelete hook for a custom or existing entity like commerce order?

Tags: commerce, entities

I need to do stuff before a [Drupal Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce) order is deleted.

[On the entity api page I found a patch](https://www.drupal.org/node/1789494) which somehow adds predelete hooks, or at least makes entities invoke those. But somehow I cant get it to work using the following code:

```
/**
 * update stock when deleting an order
 */
function mymodule_entity_predelete($entity, $type) {
  if ($type == 'commerce_order') {
    $order_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_order', $entity);

    $line_items = $order_wrapper->commerce_line_items;
    foreach ($line_items as $line_item) {
      $delete = intval($line_item->quantity->value()) * (-1);
      mymodule_update_line_item_stock_by_diff($line_item, $delete);
    }
  }
}
```

The function doesnt get called. Basically what I am trying to do is to free each line item's stock (commerce_stock) which of course is not possible when the entity is already deleted.

Do I have to extend the commerce order entity controller somehow?

Comment: The general structure of commerce assumes orders are never deleted.  Is there a reason you must delete them?  Product stock should be updated appropriately, I guess maybe not if this is for something like an order return functionality?

Comment: Well, in our application you can put a product in your cart. If the case that the cart is never checked out, the stock of that product would for ever be reserved. I know there are several more clever ways to do this rather than updating a product's stock value, but thats what we've got.
Anyways, I managed to call the predelete hook by altering the commerce order entity controller